# Problema com erro de sintaxe no else python

Tags: python-2.7

Estou tendo um problema nesse código em Python onde, quando tento executar, ele me informa que existe erro de sintaxe em um `else`. Segue o código e o erro abaixo:

```
n=int(raw_input(''))
i=0

for i in xrange(0,n):
 num_poco=int(raw_input(''))
 tipo_do_poco=raw_input('')
 custo_poco=float(raw_input(''))


 if tipo_do_poco.upper() == P or tipo_do_poco.upper() == G:
    vazao=float(raw_input(''))
    enxofre=float(raw_input(''))
    if enxofre == E:
      taxa_enxofre=float(raw_input(''))
    elif enxofre != E:
      taxa_enxofre=0.0
 else: 
    vazao=0.0
    taxa_enxofre=0.0
    lucro=0.0
    receita=0.0
 print'============================================'
 print('Empresa de Perfuracoes Furo Certo S/A.')
 print('Poco no.: %d'%(num_poco))
 print('Custo do Poco                : R$%11.2f'%(custo_poco))

 if tipo_do_poco == P:
    print('Volume de Petroleo encontrado: %11.2f'%(vazao))
    receita = vazao * 5.50 * (1 - taxa_enxofre)  
 elif tipo_do_poco == G:
    print('Volume de Gas      encontrado: %11.2f'%(vazao))
    receita = vazao * 2.20 * (1 - taxa_enxofre) 
 else:
    print('Volume de          encontrado: %11.2f'%(vazao))
    receita = 0.00
 lucro=receita-custo_poco


 if (receita - custo_poco)>50000.00:    
     print('Lucro do Poco (gusher)       : R$%11.2f\n'%(lucro)        
 else:
     print('Lucro do Poco                : R$%11.2f\n'%(lucro)   
     #print('============================================')
     #print('') 

 custo_total = (total_custo+custo_poco): 
 total_receita = (total_receita+receita): 
 total_lucro = (total_lucro+lucro):
print('=======================================')
print"Empresa de Perfuracoes Furo Certo S/A."
print('Total de Pocos          : %d'%(num_poco)
print('Total dos Custos        : R$%11.2f'%(total_custo)
print('Total da Receita        : R$%11.2f'%(total_receita)
print('Total do Lucro          : R$%11.2f'%(total_lucro)
print('=======================================')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 41
>       else:print('Lucro do Poco                : R$%11.2f\n'%(lucro)
>          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Faltou parênteses no `print` do último `else`. E parênteses no `print` do último `if` também

Comment: São tantos erros de sintaxe que é difícil listar todos. Parenteses nas linhas 40 e 42, 51, 52, 53 e 54; Dois pontos sobrando nas linhas 46, 47 e 48; Função `print` com parenteses na versão 2.7 do Python; Indentação muito esquisita para um programa em Python; e segue em frente.

Answer (score 3):

Erros de sintaxe basta você ler a mensagem que saberá o que está errado: o erro aponta para a linha 41 e se nessa linha não tem algo errado, veja a linha acima. Neste caso, faltou fechar um dos parenteses da linha 40.

```
print('Lucro do Poco (gusher)       : R$%11.2f\n' % (lucro)) 
# (faltou este parenteses) --------------------------------^
```

Além disso, aproveito para listar outros erros:

1. O mesmo erro supracitado na linha 42;
2. Dois pontos sobrando nas linhas 46, 47 e 48;
3. Parenteses faltando também nas linhas 51, 52, 53 e 54;
4. Na linha 10, há caracteres que não foram definidos devidamente como *strings*:

   ```
   if tipo_do_poco.upper() == "P" or tipo_do_poco.upper() == "G":
   ```
5. O mesmo problema do 4 acontece nas linhas 13, 15, 27 e 30;
6. Não faz sentido você definir a variável `enxofre` como *float* na linha 12 e depois compará-la com *strings*;
7. O `elif` da linha 15 é completamente desnecessário e pode ser substituído por um `else`;
8. Nenhum `raw_input` possui a identificação para o usuário de qual dado está sendo lido;
9. A indentação do código está completamente errada e inconstante; busque sempre utilizar 4 espaços para cada nível de indentação;
10. A variável `total_custo` é utilizada na linha 46, mas ela não é definida no código;
11. O mesmo para a variável `total_receita` na linha 47;
12. E para a variável `total_lucro` na linha 48;
13. Na linha 52 você exibe a variável `total_custo`, mas só define a `custo_total`;

Corrija isso e o programa (provavelmente) executará sem erros - o que não significa que está correto.

Comment: Gostei particularmente da ultima frase! lol

Answer (score 2):

Arthur, quando voce for usar o `%` para demarcar aonde voce quer o valor de determinada variavel dentro de seu print o mesmo deve seguir a seguinte sintaxe:

```
print('quero falar dessa % variável ' %(variavel))
```

No seu caso foi omitido o parêntesis no final. Por isso esta mostrando o erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Exato, ja editei. perdão